# Price does not accumulate if user repeat order

Tags: c++

First of all, sorry if this is a dumb question.

These are my 2 functions. I'm trying to make a repeated order in function listHardware as you can see, "Do you want to purchase more? Press y for yes." at the bottom of the function. But if user repeat order, only the new price will be displayed. Why does not it accumulate with the previous price of their previous order?

I thought I made it right by doing price+= in calcFunc.

```
void listHardware()
{
    int i,j,type,m_type,c_type,r_type,s_type,g_type,quantity=0;
    const int SIZE=3;
    char shopmember,addorder = 'y';
    double price=0;

    while(addorder=='Y' || addorder=='y')
    {
    cout << endl << "Select which type of hardware that you want to purchase: ";
    cin >> type;

    if(type==1)
    {
        const char *monitor[SIZE][2]=
        {
            {"BenQ PD3200U", "(RM3000)"},
            {"Acer Predator X34", "(RM4000)"},
            {"Dell UltraSharp UP3218K", "(RM8000)"}
        };

        cout << "Monitors:" << endl;
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << i+1 << ". ";
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                cout << monitor[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter which Monitor you would like to purchase: ";
        cin >> m_type; //monitor
        cout << endl << "How many Monitor would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
    }
    if(type==2)
    {
        const char *cpu[SIZE][2]=
        {
            {"AMD Ryzen 7 2700X", "(RM1200)"},
            {"Intel Core i5-8600K", "(RM1200)"},
            {"Intel Core i9-7980XE", "(RM8000)"}
        };

        cout << "CPU:" << endl;
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << i+1 << ". ";
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                cout << cpu[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter which CPU would you like to purchase: ";
        cin >> c_type; //cpu
        cout << endl << "How many CPU would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
    }
    if(type==3)
    {
        const char *ram[SIZE][2]=
        {
            {"Patriot Viper Elite 8GB DDR4-2400MHz", "(RM400)"},
            {"G.Skill Ripjaws V 16GB DDR4-2400MHz", "(RM1200)"},
            {"Corsair Dominator Platinum 32GB DDR4-3333MHz", "(RM2000)"}
        };

        cout << "RAM:" << endl;
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << i+1 << ". ";
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                cout << ram[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter which RAM would you like to purchase: ";
        cin >> r_type; //ram
        cout << endl << "How many RAM would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
    }
    if(type==4)
    {
        const char *ssd[SIZE][2]=
        {
            {"Samsung 860 Pro 1TB", "(RM1250)"},
            {"Crucial MX500 1TB", "(RM600)"},
            {"WD Blue 2TB", "(RM1600)"}
        };

        cout << "SSD:" << endl;
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << i+1 << ". ";
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                cout << ssd[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter which SSD would you like to purchase: ";
        cin >> s_type; //ssd
        cout << endl << "How many SSD would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
    }
    if(type==5)
    {
        const char *gcard[SIZE][2]=
        {
            {"Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 Ti", "(RM4000)"},
            {"Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Ti", "(RM2900)"},
            {"AMD Radeon RX 580 8GB", "(RM2100)"}
        };

        cout << "Graphic Card:" << endl;
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << i+1 << ". ";
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                cout << gcard[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter which Graphic Card would you like to purchase: ";
        cin >> g_type; //gpu
        cout << endl << "How many Graphic Card would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
    }

    cout << "Membership (Y/N): ";
    cin >> shopmember;

    cout << "Do you want to purchase more? Press y for yes." << endl;
    cin >> addorder;
    cin.ignore();

    price=calcFunc(m_type,c_type,r_type,s_type,g_type,quantity,price,shopmember); //function call
    }

    cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;
    cout << "Total Price: " << price << endl;
    cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;
}
```

//

```
double calcFunc(int m_type,int c_type,int r_type, int s_type, int g_type,int quantity,double price, char shopmember)
{
    const double discount=0.1;

    if(m_type==1) //monitor
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(3000-(3000*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=3000*quantity;
    }
    else if(m_type==2) //monitor
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(4000-(4000*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=4000*quantity;
    }
    else if(m_type==3) //monitor
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(8000-(8000*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=8000*quantity;
    }

    if(c_type==1) //cpu
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(1200-(1200*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=1200*quantity;
    }
    else if(c_type==2) //cpu
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(1200-(1200*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=1200*quantity;
    }
    else if(c_type==3) //cpu
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(8000-(8000*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=8000*quantity;
    }

    if(r_type==1) //ram
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(400-(400*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=400*quantity;
    }
    else if(r_type==2) //ram
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(1200-(1200*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=1200*quantity;
    }
    else if(r_type==3) //ram
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(2000-(2000*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=2000*quantity;
    }

    if(s_type==1) //ssd
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(1250-(1250*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=1250*quantity;
    }
    else if(s_type==2) //ssd
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(600-(600*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=600*quantity;
    }
    else if(s_type==3) //ssd
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(1600-(1600*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=1600*quantity;
    }

    if(g_type==1) //gpu
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(4000-(4000*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=4000*quantity;
    }
    else if(g_type==2) //gpu
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(2900-(2900*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=2900*quantity;
    }
    else if(g_type==3) //gpu
    {
        if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
            price+=(2100-(2100*discount))*quantity;
        else
            price+=2100*quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: It fixed now but my codes have logic error (sometimes when repeating order). After I experimental with its output I detect that when I repeat order, the price before will change to the current price. For example if I did my first order with price of 2000, then after repeat the second order with price of 3000, the total should be 2000+3000 after finish the order. But somehow the price of the first order change to next price which then will be 3000+3000 (notice the first one is error, should be 2000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double calcFunc(int m_type,int c_type,int r_type, int s_type, int g_type,int quantity,double price, char shopmember)
```

Is missing a return statement.
Add

```
return price;
```

at the end of the function and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks its working. But my codes have logic error (sometimes when repeating order). After I experimental with its output I detect that when I repeat order, the price before will change to the current price. For example if I did my first order with price of 2000, then after repeat the second order with price of 3000, the total should be 2000+3000 after finish the order. But somehow the price of the first order change to next price which then will be 3000+3000 (notice the first one is error, should be 2000)